# Why boxing is preferred over var-args?

Tags: java

I know from JLS that widening is preferred over boxing and boxing is preferred over var-args.

I understand that, widening is legacy methodology and designers tend to keep it as a priority. What i fail to understand is why boxing is preferred over var-args. Here are my two concerns.

1. Why boxing is preferred over var-args?
2. How behind the scenes boxing and var-args is interpreted?

Can someone explain with an example?

As i understand, Var-args basically build an Arraytype to hold number of parameters provided. As i know array is an an object. I would like to demonstrate my confusion with this example

```
// 1 Object is made which is basically a wrapper
public void boxing(Integer i); 
// 1 object made which is an Array
public void boxing(int.. x)
```

In both cases, one object is made. Then the former is faster path than the later?

Thanks,

Comment: IMO it makes sense to keep varargs the lowest priority. As to your second question (*How behind the scenes boxing and var-args is interpreted?*), I don't understand it.

Comment: My second point means that how compiler interprets var-args behind the scene, does it make some kind of array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524079/why-primitive-type-will-call-first-rather-than-wrapper-classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, var-args boxes and un-boxes into Arrays of *type*, so I see them as complimentary, not exclusive choices.

Now, for performance reasons, you might select one over another in many cases, because creating objects unnecessarily is an expense you don't need to pay.  That's why there are many times when an var-arg method comes with its zero-arg, one-arg, two-arg, and three-arg cousins.  The various equivalent calls bind before the var-arg version, providing a faster path for the (hopefully common) low arg count versions of the var-arg call.

Where people may be using var-args over boxing is where they tend to var-arg into a generic type list, like (Object... parameters) over (Int x, Float precision, Boolean visible), but that's just bad practice in my opinion.

--- Editing answer in response to edit of question ---

So the two scenarios are

```
// 1 Object is made which is basically a wrapper
public void boxing(Integer i);

// 1 object made which is an Array
public void boxing(int.. x)
```

The only call scenario that makes sense for these to be replaceable is the one-arg call scenario.  Zero, and two args are not supported by the first boxing method, so they cannot be seen as valid parameter lists if we are talking about the two boxing methods being equivalent.

So functionally, the latter one is incorrect when called like

```
boxing(5, 4);
```

And performance wise, it is also a hit when called like

```
boxing(null);
```

As the first one doesn't require any boxing at all, While the second one will require converting the null to an array of zero elements, so you don't get null pointer exceptions when attempting to un-box the array within the function.

So, if you have an optional single primitive argument, use boxing instead of var-args, because varargs is both conceptually wrong (by allowing extra parameters), and in the case of not having a value, a performance hit (to create a zero-length array).

Note: for the null parameter call to work in many cases, you need a cast.

```
boxing((Integer)null);
```

And I can only imagine what kind of boxing shennagins this would create if you tried

```
boxing((int)null);
```

Comment: by zero-arg, two-arg cousins you means, methods with zero argument and one argument? I understood your points. Thanks a ton Edwin.

Comment: Yes, like a series of related calls in the same class; `func(Integer first)`, `func(Integer first, Integer second)`, `func(Integer first, Integer second, Integer third)`, `func(Integer... ints)`.  The only reason the specific number of arg calls exist is to prevent the boxing from creating the array, which is a performance improvement for the low-arg-count calls.

Comment: thanks so much, i understood the answer perfectly well. Thank you so much.

Comment: i have just one curiosity. When we say, var-args kind of make an Array of type. Array is an object as well as in Boxing objects are made also. How come then var-args will provide a faster path. In case of Array one object is made, in case of Boxing, lets say if its comes with two-arg cousin, two objects are made. Then how we say boxing is faster path appraoch?

Comment: Perhaps you misread my comment, or perhaps I woreded it awkwardly.  They don't add in the one, two, and three parameter calls because the var-args is faster, they add it in because the var-args is slower, and if the parameter count can match a written fixed-parameter call, then the var-args won't be called at all.  The var-args is slower, because the JVM has to build an array to hold the variable number of parameters, which it doesn't have to do with a fixed-parameter scenario.

Comment: I think the "boxing is faster" approach only applies to the scenarios where varargs would be abused.  For example, better to box types into similar types instead of using a varargs of "Object", and then do some sort of index based casting on the other end.

Comment: actually i have tried to explain my confusion in my question. I edited the question. Can you see my edit, may be than my confusion is cleared to you. Thanks.

Comment: Saw the edit and updated the answer to keep this from being an extended chat in the commentary.

Comment: amazing thanks so much @Edwin. It makes such a perfect sense now.

Comment: @benz It's a pleasure, and even moreso because you're obviously really getting into the language.  I hope you have fun and achieve your goals.  Considering your obvious motivation, I expect you will!

Comment: Thanks Edwin for your encouraging words. Means a ton. :).